# IE security settings set to high - javascript not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

As soon as I set the IE security settings to high the javascript on my page stops executing. It doesn't throw an error or anything, and not even alert works. if I set the security settings back to medium everything works as it should. 
Has anybody ever experienced something like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behavior is by design.
The `High` security setting disables Javascript.

Answer (score 7):

Setting security settings to high in Internet Explorer disables JavaScript:

[image: High Security Settings]

Answer (score 0):

you can use "noscript" tag to display a message when javascript is disabled. But as you can guess, you can not write javascript inside that block.