# Got security prompt for "yui.yahooapis.com" with security set to High on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, yui

I include YUI library locally, but when I have IE security set to High I got alert saying yui.yahooapis.com is not trusted.

How can I get rid of the http request and make the library totally local?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is by design.  When you have IE security set to high, all JavaScript is disabled.

[IE security settings set to high - javascript not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248653/ie-security-settings-set-to-high-javascript-not-working)