# Problems in my website when opened in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer

Well ... I'll try to explain my problem:

I made a new website and it's works in Firefox, Safari, Internet Explorer, Chrome... but I've seen one problem: When Internet Explorer has a High Level of Security, my website doesn't work!

I don't understood why because all the files are loaded but ... it's like IE loads the files but isn't reading them.

Here's my "header.php":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />  
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"/>

<title>
    <?php if ( is_home() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php bloginfo('description'); ?><?php } ?>
    <?php if ( is_author() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | Archivo por autor<?php } ?>
    <?php if ( is_single() ) { ?><?php wp_title(''); ?> | <?php wp_title(''); ?><?php } ?>
    <?php if ( is_page() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php wp_title(''); ?><?php } ?>
    <?php if ( is_category() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php single_cat_title(); ?><?php } ?>
    <?php if ( is_month() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php the_time('F'); ?><?php } ?>
    <?php if ( is_search() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | Resultados<?php } ?>
    <?php if (function_exists('is_tag')) { if ( is_tag() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | Archivo por Tag | <?php  single_tag_title("", true); } } ?>
</title>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var activaMapa = 1;          
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>       
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>       
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/js/html5_code.js"></script>       
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/js/css3_code.js"></script>       
   <script type="text/javascript">    
        activaMapa = 0;
   </script>
<![endif]-->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <style>
 article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display: block;}
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript">     
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.oscurece').show('fade',400,function(){
                $('html,body').css({position:'fixed'});
                $('.aviso-navigator').show('fade',1600);
            });
        },400);
        $('.cierra-avisoNavigator').click(function(){
            $('.aviso-navigator').hide('fade',400,function(){
                $('html,body').css({position:'inherit'});
                $('.oscurece').hide('fade',1600);
            });
        });
    });
 </script>
 <![endif]-->

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/favicon.ico"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" media="screen" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />    

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter:400,700%7COpen+Sans:400,600,700"/>    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/js/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/js/slicknav/slicknav.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/js/shadowbox/shadowbox.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/slicknav/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/js/isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/js/popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/js/shadowbox/shadowbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/js/controles.js"></script>
```

The website is made in Wordpress, as you can see in the code.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What does mean : `When Internet Explorer have a High Level of Security` ?

Comment: Sorry...when you see the option Tools >> Internet Options >> Security >> Internet and move the scroll to High :) (sorry for my English jeje)

Comment: Maybe it makes Internet Explorer stop to understand Javascript code... So it won't understand the HTML5Shim, and then the website is ugly

Comment: I think so to..but, when I try to enable HTML5 with something like article,nav,section{display:block!important;} isn't works :( :(

Comment: html5 tags are not supported in ie8

Answer (score 1):

High security settings in IE8 will disable javascript from running - see [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248653/ie-security-settings-set-to-high-javascript-not-working)

Thus, your 'activaMapa' variable won't be set, the html5shim won't load, etc. What you do about this will rather depend on whether you can do without the Javascript.

Comment: Well...it's ok if block all the script, but what happend with my style.css? If comment all <script> or delete and put the something like "article,nav,section{display:block!important;}" to "enable" html5 in IE8, I have the same results :(

Comment: Well, it will depend on what you mean by 'doesn't work.' In the file above, you're using a large number of jQuery libraries and inline Javascript. None of these will work, and this is likely to have a sizeable and nigh unpredictable effect on the page. 

I suggest you find the security settings mentioned in the question I linked, try toggling javascript, and see what changes.

Comment: When I said "doesn't work", I'm thinking in the styles, functionality...but I'm seen the problem only happend in IE who works in servers (with this type of configuration..). In a "normal" (in your personal computer or notebook) IE9 or lower the website works, because his configuration of security, normally it's "middle". And...sorry for explain in my poor english...