# How to run javascript on high security setting of Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

here is my code it work on medium security setting of IE but no at High here is my sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>TEST</title>   
   <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document.documentElement).ready(function() {
            alert('hi');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE security settings set to high - javascript not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248653/ie-security-settings-set-to-high-javascript-not-working)

Comment: You can't.
[It was already asked.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248653/ie-security-settings-set-to-high-javascript-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

By Default, JavaScript is disabled in HIGH security Settings.

maybe this could help you: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315674